# Ajax запросы с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Изучаю ajax запросы. Нашёл на metanit пример в mvc проекте. Вот например вызов формы ajax запросом.

```
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
    }

    <div id="results"></div>

</div>
```

Но тут используется c# хелперы. А как написать то же самое с помощью jquery?
Нашёл примеры ajax запросов с помощью jquery которые начинаются примерно так:

```
$.ajax({
});
```

Но не могу понять как сделать то же самое что реализовано у меня с помощью хелперов. Подскажите пожалуйста как это должно выглядеть?

Код View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" id="Search" value="Поиск" name="btn" />

    @section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('[name = "btn"]').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/BookSearch",
                    data: { "name": $('#txt').val }
                });
            });
        </script>
    }

    <div id="results"></div>

</div>
```

Код контроллера:

```
Context db = new Context();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BookSearch(string name)
        {
            var allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Author.Contains(name)).ToList();

            if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(allbooks);
        }
```

И ошибка на клиенте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Примерно как во [вчерашнем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922039/213987) вопросе.

Comment: Или [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809366/213987) (версия для asp.net core) или [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840849/213987). Мне кажется, вы можете найти кучу образцов на so, гитхабе или просто в сети, вбив ключевые слова.

Comment: @AK попробовал написать, не работает кнопка, сейчас в вопрос скину код подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: @AK понял свою ошибку, я только изучаю jquery)) Нужны были скобки после val. Но вот не понял как дальше результат положить куда я хочу? В примере с хелпером есть update target а как тут сделать такое же?

Comment: @AK всё и с этим разобрался, спасибо за подсказку и ссылки на варианты.

Comment: @AK а подскажите пожалуйста, вот в ajax запросе можно посмотреть результат выполнения запроса и в зависимости от результата выбрать необходимое действие. Например если запрос выполнился то выдать нужное мне сообщение а в случае ошибки другое. А как сделать то же самое без помощь ajax? То есть например с обычными post get запросами. например <form method="post" ...... и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {    
        $.ajax({
      url: 'php.php', //твой url куда будет отправлен запрос
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
                TOId: 'vlad' //твой параметр
            },
      beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        $('.btnTOEdit').text('Загрузка, 5 сек...');  
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        var $ajax_response = $( data );
        $( '#result' ).html( $ajax_response ); //в id="result"    запишутся те дание, которые ты получил с сервера
      }
    });
    });
```

Comment: <?php
echo 'test'; - етот ответ запишется в твой блок id="result"