# Как отправить переменную с js на без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Есть переменная, a её нужно отравить в php код. Как это можно реализовать?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=1; // переменная a которую нужно отправить на php без перезагрузки страницы
</script>


<?php 
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это называется `ajax`. И здесь и в интернете - сведений вагон.

Comment: в интернете нет нормальных примеров думал может тут кто нибудь покажет самое простое действие

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922079/ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery

Comment: там как то странно всё,мне нужно буквально очень простой пример хотябы посмотреть как работает всё

Comment: Для начала прочитать и осознать http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Файл index.php

// Скрипт php и js на одной странице

// Если была отправлена переменная, то возвращаем ее и завершаем скрипт

if (isset($_GET['a'])) {

    $a = $_GET['a'];

    echo json_encode([
        'a' => $a
    ]);

    die();
}

?>

<!-- Если переменная не была передана, то загружаем страницу которая сразу же отправляет переменную -->
<!-- Для отправки воспользуемся функцией getJSON из библиотеки jQuery -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        var a = 1;

        $.getJSON('index.php', {a: a}).done(function (result) {
            alert(result.a);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо тут могу я дать лучший ответ? если да то подскажите как